# Draw custom shadow on label

Tags: ios, xamarin, uilabel, shadow, uibezierpath

[image: Example label]

I'm trying to achieve this kind of shadow, my research led me to using the `CGPathRef`to draw the shadow myself, but I can't figure out how it actually works.

Drawing the `label.layer.shadowPath` looks like a good plan, can anyone show me/point me to how I should proceed?

EDIT : I'm now to the point of trying to draw a UIBezierPath based on the string in the current label, the path being the actual shape of the shadow I need. I'm not sure that's the best option but it looks more promising.

EDIT 2 : Here is the code i'm now working with. this outlines the text of the label as an image, but it's pretty much the exact same text as the label itself, i still have to work my way around making it look like a shadow. Note, we're using `Xamarin`

```
public override void Draw (CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
        {
            base.Draw (rect);
            using (CGContext g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ()) {

                UIBezierPath completePath = UIBezierPath.Create ();

                g.ScaleCTM (1, -1);
                g.TranslateCTM (2, -(this.Bounds.Height / 2) - (this.Font.LineHeight / 3));

                CTLine line = new CTLine (this.AttributedText);
                CTRun[] runs = line.GetGlyphRuns ();

                for (int i = 0; i < runs.Length; i++) {

                    CTRun run = runs [i];
                    CTFont font = run.GetAttributes ().Font;

                    for (int j = 0; j < run.GlyphCount; j++) {

                        NSRange currentRange = new NSRange (j, 1);
                        CGPoint[] positions = run.GetPositions (currentRange); 
                        ushort[] glyphs = run.GetGlyphs (currentRange);

                        CGPath letter = font.GetPathForGlyph (glyphs [0]);
                        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation (positions [0].X, positions [0].Y);

                        CGPath path = new CGPath (letter, transform);
                        UIBezierPath newPath = UIBezierPath.FromPath (path);
                        completePath.AppendPath (newPath);
                    }
                }


                completePath.LineWidth = 1;

                UIColor.Red.SetStroke ();
                UIColor.Blue.SetFill ();
                completePath.Stroke ();
                completePath.Fill ();


                completePath.ClosePath ();

                //Here I will try to loop over my current points and go down & right at every step of the loop, see how it goes performance-wise. Instead of one complex drawing I'll just have a very simple drawing that has thousands of points :o
                g.AddPath (completePath.CGPath);
                g.DrawPath (CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to achieve this effect. You have to implement the drawing code on your own.

Here are two ideas to create the shadow:

- Draw the text in dark blue color, repeated n times, starting from the original position in 0.5 pt. steps shifted down right. This has bad performance but is really easy to implement.
- Find the text outline using Core Text and implement some algorithm that creates the actual outline of the shadow. This could then be used as the `shadowPath` property.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I'm actually headed for your second option, but finding a way to know the exact shape is a bit tricky.
I need my label in a tableview, repeated multiple times, so your first option is funny at best :P

Comment: @Zil Did you actually try the first solution? It seems simple enough, and maybe it's not so bad, after all. Calculating the extruded path is definitely more involved, regarding code size and complexity.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, and I had read your first step wrong. I thought you meant copying the actual label n times, not drawing it.

I've managed to get the drawing of all points of my text now, i'll try to copy it n times downards and see how it goes ^^My code is pretty shady but it does the job.